# Transforming a PDE to an ODE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Considering the problem:
$$4\xi\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\chi}-\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial\xi^2}=0\qquad\quad(\chi,\xi)\in(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$$
$$\theta(0,\xi)=1\qquad\quad\xi\in(0,\infty)$$
$$\theta(\chi,0)=0\qquad\quad\chi\in(0,\infty)$$
And knowing that it is invariant to the following transformation
$$\chi\to\lambda\chi\quad\text y \quad\xi\to\lambda^\frac{1}{3}\xi$$
Rewrite the previous boundary problem  for an ODE that solves a function f such that
$$\theta(\chi,\xi)=f(\frac{\chi}{\xi^3}) $$

I've been trying to rewrite using that transformation but I can't seem to figure it out, so I'm looking for a bit of help.

Comment: In the problem an = is missing

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate partial derivative and put it in main PDE.
$$
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \chi} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \chi} = \frac{df}{dx} 
\frac{\partial (\frac{\chi}{\xi^3})}{\partial \chi} = \frac{1}{\xi^3} \frac{df}{dx}
$$
which $x = (\frac{\chi}{\xi^3})$ is variable of $f$, similarly for $\xi$ :
$$
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \xi} =  \frac{df}{dx} (-3 \frac{\chi}{\xi^4})
$$
second derivative :
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial \xi^2} = \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} (-3 \frac{\chi}{\xi^4})^2 +12 \frac{df}{dx} ( \frac{\chi}{\xi^5})
$$
substituting in PDE :
$$
4 \xi (\frac{1}{\xi^3} \frac{df}{dx}) - 9 \frac{\chi^2}{\xi^8} \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} - 12 \frac{\chi}{\xi^5}\frac{df}{dx} =0
$$
multiply by $\xi^2$ ,finally you get :
$$
4(1-3x)\frac{df}{dx} - 9 x^2 \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} =0 \quad , x \in [0,\infty)
$$
Boundaries are :
$$
f(0) = 1 \quad f(\infty) = 0
$$

Comment: You are likely missing a second derivative. I am expecting a $d^{2}f/dx^{2}$ term in the transformed ODE.

Comment: you're right. I correct it.